# Suggestions on how to format a number as currency in IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: watson-assistant

I am not able to figure out how to format amounts (integer, decimal, etc..) as currency in IBM Watson Assistant.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities#system-entities-sys-currency

Comment: Give an example of your inputs and the expected outputs. I can print `4 €` and `5 $`or `5,02 USD`

Comment: The inputs could be 1102.5; 11000 etc...The expected output in these cases should be $1,102.50; $11,000.00

Comment: I am using this right now (from https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-strings-java-lang-String) :  {
  <? T(String).format('%.2f',<number to format>) ?>
}
For example, if the $number variable that needs to be formatted in US dollars is 4.5, then a response such as, Your total is $<? T(String).format('%.2f',$number) ?> returns Your total is $4.50. But this does not add the thousand separator (the comma).

Answer (score 0):

There are additional details here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

T(String).format('%,.2f',$number)